tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x7c4b17a48610 state=finished raised APIRemovedInV1>]
I used the below code :
rerank = SentenceTransformerRerank(
    model="cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-2-v2", top_n=3
)
response_synthesizer = get_response_synthesizer(streaming=True)
try:
    vector_retriever = self._vector_index.as_retriever(
        similarity_top_k=10)
    keyword_retriever = self._keyword_index.as_retriever()
    custom_retriever = CustomRetriever(
        vector_retriever, keyword_retriever)
    custom_query_engine = RetrieverQueryEngine(
        retriever=custom_retriever, response_synthesizer=response_synthesizer, node_postprocessors=[rerank])
    response = custom_query_engine.query(query)
    answer = generatorize_response(response.response_gen)

But when i this then it will showing an error:
tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x7c4b17a48610 state=finished raised APIRemovedInV1>]

Help needed! Thanks in Advance
My configuration of key and related things are correct.
